# Customise HTML5 video - only show volume controls

Tags: html, html5-video

I would like to customise html5 video, and only display the volume controls, I want it to autoplay on load, and hide the rest of the controls. I also want to show a play again button at the end. All help appreciated!

```
 <video id="video_1"                             
                          autoplay="autoplay"  width="100%" height="264"
                          poster="videos/benstatue.jpg"
                          >
                         <source src="videos/benstatue.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
                         <source src="videos/benstatue.webm" type='video/webm' />
                         <source src="videos/benstatue.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
                        </video>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should first research a bit what you are trying to accomplish and ask a question when you encounter a problem.

Answer (score 1):

with the controls attribute you can enable all controlls. if you want only the volume controll you must make it with JavaScript. Here is a tutorial: http://www.broken-links.com/2009/10/06/building-html5-video-controls-with-javascript/

you can also use a libary http://www.videojs.com/